# The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))". (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

Tags: ssis

SSIS package execution failing with below message:
Exception deserializing the package "The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))". (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

SQL Server version info:
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019-Version 16.6.1
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.6.1+30128.74
Microsoft .NET Framework - Version 4.8.03752
SQL Server Analysis Services   15.0.1572.0
Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services Designer Version 15.0.1572.0
SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.62004.28040
SQL Server Integration Services   15.0.1301.433
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer-Version 15.0.1301.433
SQL Server Reporting Services   15.0.1528.0
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers -Version 15.0.1528.0

Answer (score 0):

This problem resolved. 
There was message displaying within VSTS2019 tool for updates. Installed all those updates and now, all packages are getting executed without any issues. Just, installed all those updates and nothing else. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Right Click on the Solution ->Configuration Properties->Configuration Manager

Here you create new configurations.

[image]